# Div 1:1 ratio with image inside, with a viewport maxheight, no scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm trying to find a way to do the following:

1. Have 2 divs, each with an image as a child element, each 50% width of current viewport
2. Scale each of these two divs in a 1:1 aspect ratio, and let the image inside each of them fill as good as possible
3. Never make the divs larger (width or height) so that we get scrollbars in our browser..

Am I asking for the impossible? Or is there a way to do this in css?

For example, let's say I have viewport of 1800x700 px. That would mean each of my columns would have dimensions of 900x900 if run the code below. But my viewport is only 700px heigh = I get scrollbars..

```
.columns-ratio-slide-container{
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;

    .col-container{
        width: 50%;
        padding-top: 50%;
        position: relative;
        float: left;

        @include debug();
        .half{

            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            img{
                display: block;
                max-height: 100%;
                &.landscape{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML structure:

```
<div class="columns-ratio-slide-container">
    <div class="col-container">
        <div class="half">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/480x640">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-container">
        <div class="half">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/640x320">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See this image if that helps...
[image: Sketch of what Im trying to achieve]

Comment: If you want to make images full width/height of div, you can do the following: `.background-image {
  background-image: url(path);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}`

Comment: @Pete Yes, updated.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Yes, but that does not solve the issue with the divs getting to high while trying to maintain their 1:1 aspect ratio. Background size with cover also cuts of the image if it does not fit its container.

Comment: Are the images part of content or layout/design? Becase background images and `img` elements are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `50vw` and `100vh` to get what you want. Here is an example code snippet:

EDIT: use `flex` layout to put 2 divs in horizontal center place and update the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cshao/54amto04/4/). Also, describe how to deal with header and footer.

```css
*
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
div.container
{
    width: 50vw; 
    height: 50vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vh;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
}
.container1 {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('https://img3.doubanio.com/lpic/s4554820.jpg');
}
.container2 {
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url('http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/simgad/10067268081911489671');
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container1 container"></div>
  <div class="container2 container"></div>
</div>
```

A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cshao/54amto04/4/) is also made. You can adjust the view area's width/height, these 2 divs' aspect ratio are always 1:1, and no scrollbar will appear.

If header or footer is needed, you can use `calc()` on `max-height` and `max-width`, such as:

```
max-height: calc(100vh - 80px); // 80px is the sum of header height and footer height.
max-width: calc(100vh - 80px);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot.

Comment: is this something by the way that can be a problem with IE10? Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Sorry - was another problem with IE :) However, Safari on Mac seems to have a problem while resizing, at some different viewport sizes, the image (an actual img tag) inside a container gets all squeezed up, like loosing ratio. But on reload, it all looks fine...?

Comment: It seems like a bug in Safari on Mac. One potential workaround is: 1. listen to `window`'s `resize` event. 2, when `resize` happens, hide `<img>` element and use the picture as background. 3, when `resize` ends, disable the background and show `<img>` again.

Comment: cool, will try that. By the way - on the column layout, if I wanna just have one column, that can contain either portrait and landscape images, what would the best way to go then in order to get as much visible as possible from the picture, but still mind header and footer when resizing?

Comment: @nickelman that's easy, just put `width` and `height` of `div.container` as `100vw` and you are good to go.

Comment: right! But then I would still get a 1:1 ratio for lets say a more of landscape image, and it feels like there could be more wider in that ratio, or am I thinking to much out of the box then? :)

Comment: do you mean you don't need 1:1 ratio any more? If yes, just play with `width`/`height` and `max-width`/`max-height` and you will get what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "display: table-row" and "display: table-cell"

```css
.columns-ratio-slide-container {
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.col-container{
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.col-container img{
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns-ratio-slide-container">
    <div class="col-container">
        <div class="half">
            <img class="landscape" src="http://placehold.it/480x640">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-container">
        <div class="half ">
            <img class="landscape" src="http://placehold.it/640x320">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves my issue? I get scrollbars, and none of the columns are in a 1:1 aspect ratio?